# Trouble processing incoming JSON with rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

I have a Registrations controller (overrides the devise controller) that should receive a JSON hash and then register a new user. However, the new user save always fails, but I can't figure out why.

Here's my controller:

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def create

    @user = User.new(params[user_params])

    if @user.save
      render json: @user.as_json(auth_token: user.authentication_token, email: user.email), status: 201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render json: @user.errors, status: 422
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require[:registration].permit(:email, :password, :name, :phone, :acknowledgement) if params.present?
  end

end
```

My User model includes validation for email, phone, name and acknowledgement

To test the controller, I am using the following command:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/registrations -d "{\"email\":\"user1@example.com\",\"name\":\"anotheruser\",\"phone\":\"250.717.7265\",\"acknowledgement\":\"true\"}"
```

I get this output from running the command:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fef04004000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fef04004000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/registrations HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 98
>
* upload completely sent off: 98 out of 98 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 409196ef-657d-4420-be59-9ff632699d23
< X-Runtime: 0.013133
* Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22) is not blacklisted
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22)
< Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2014 23:47:34 GMT
< Content-Length: 168
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"email":["can't be blank","can't be blank"],"name":["can't be blank"],"phone":["can't be blank","Must be in 555.555.5555 format"],"acknowledgement":["can't be blank"]}
```

My webserver is giving me this output:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/registrations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-25 15:43:43 -0800
Processing by Api::V1::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"user1@example.com", "name"=>"anotheruser", "phone"=>"250.717.7265", "acknowledgement"=>"true", "registration"=>{"email"=>"user1@example.com", "name"=>"anotheruser", "phone"=>"250.717.7265", "acknowledgement"=>"true"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 7ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Obviously it's not creating a new user like I thought it would but I can't figure out why. If anyone could help me see what's wrong I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `curl` request to look like this:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'\
 -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/registrations 
\-d "{\"registration\":{\"email\":\"user1@example.com\",\"name\":\"anotheruser\",\"phone\":\"250.717.7265\",\"acknowledgement\":\"true\"}}"
```

You are not supplying the `registration` that you `require` in your `user_params` method

#### EDIT

Change:

```
@user = User.new(params[user_params])
```

to:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: I thought that too, but you can see that the registration hash is already in the params hash when you look at the webserver output.

I did try the curl request as you suggested though but the results are still the same as my initial issues.

Comment: I did try the suggestion exactly as you suggested but the results were the same as originally.